# Is there any way to know is it a zepto object?

Tags: zepto

I tried `"$('#m') instanceof $"`,then I got false.
how do I know it is a zepto object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this exact same problem while trying to use [Zepto matchers for Jasmine](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jasmine-zepto). It seems like Zepto wraps objects using an internal Z function that is only accessible by the closure. I tried exposing it by mapping it to $.Z, which works

```
$(el) instanceof $.Z // => true
```

but it still doesn't work with the matchers for some reason. I have created an [issue](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/issues/349) on Zepto's github, so hopefully it's something that can be added in.